# How can I import a project in NWDS Web Dynpro from NetWeaver

Tags: java, netweaver, webdynpro

I have to complete the work of a colleague who is ill. My problem is I cannot talk to him and cannot work with his files or his computer.

I can see the Project in the component browser of the PO. I have imported some files in my workspace but I cannot work with them in the Web Dynpro explorer.

Does somebody know what to do?

Have I imported the files wrong or is there any additional step I have missed?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to Development Infrastructure, find your project, right click on it and choose 'Create Project', later on ask your collegue to check-in all of his changes and sync the project in Development Infrastructure on 'Open Activites' tab.

Make sure you are not working on the same component simultaneously as version controll will give you a very hard time and it is most likely that one of you  will loose the changes.